# How to swap case with Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I tried to make a one line function to swap a string cases but it doesn't work. Everything makes sense, but the function is returning the same string passed in it without any changes.

```
import re

def swap_case(string):
    return re.sub('([A-Z])([a-z]+)', r'\1'.lower()+'\2'.upper(), string)
```

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use `str.swapcase()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern may not match the structure of the input string, e.g. if the first character be lowercase followed by the second uppercase.  Here is a version using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
def swap_case(string):
    return re.sub(r'.', lambda x: x.group().upper() if x.group() == x.group().lower() else x.group().lower(), string)

inp = "Hello World"
print(swap_case(inp))  # hELLO wORLD
```

The above solution works by toggling each character from lowercase to uppercase or vice-versa.

Comment: It's matching the string , if i try to add a space in front of the group it will work but I can't change the case.

Comment: Your logic is off, because you want to toggle the case of _every_ character, not just upper followed by lower.

Comment: Oh, that's cool.  Tried something similar as `lambda x: x.group().upper() or x.group().lower()` but that didn't do it, so decided on iterating through each letter.

Answer (score 1):

Think that's the right idea, but it doesn't want to do a string conversion to `.lower()` or `.upper()` until those values are returned from the regex operation.  Not sure how you'd do that as a one-liner.  They've got a couple different iteration methods.  `.findall()` did alright, 'cuz you could print each letter out and see what it was doing easily.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import re 

def swap_case( string ):
    newstring = ''
    for s in re .findall( r'([\w ]{1})', string ):
        ##  print( s )
        try: newstring += re .match( r'([A-Z ])', s ) .group(1) .lower()
        except: newstring += re .match( r'([a-z])', s ) .group(1) .upper()
    return newstring

print(  swap_case( 'THIS is A string' )  )
```

> this IS a STRING

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: You might want to get rid of all regex stuff here, and just iterate the input string directly.

Comment: Yea, I agree, though he was specifically looking for a regex solution.  Maybe it's a bit much, but it still helps illustrate why the OP didn't run, because it didn't have a test in there for the upper vs lower conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, your rexexp may not match the input string. As an alternative solution, here's a simple one-liner which works by iterating over the characters of the string:

```
def swapcase(s):
    return ''.join(ch.upper() if ch.islower() else ch.lower() for ch in s)
```

Of course, you could also simply use `str.swapcase()`; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase.